# Change Automatic Generated WSDL 2.0 in WSO2 Application Server

Tags: wsdl, wso2, apache-axis

**How can I change WSDL2.0 of a service that will be deployed on WSO2 Application Server?**

I want to change *WSDL* content of a service that developed and will be deployed on WSO2 Application Server. I moved custom *WSDL* file to `META-INF` directory and set `useOriginalwsdl=true` property. but only *WSDL* version 1.1 is that affected by this property. I want to use the custom *WSDL 2.0* for my service in WSO2 Application Server. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Application Server uses Axis2 1.6.x and useOriginalwsdl=true is in fact not supported for WSDL 2.0. See following JIRA.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5191

According to the JIRA, it is fixed in Axis2 1.7.0, which is not yet released.

If you really want to use that feature, it might be easier to patch the existing version of Axis2. The fix attached to the JIRA is simple, but I'm not really sure how much code changes are required. The patch is provided for axis2 trunk and therefore I cannot really tell without trying first!

Also the code for Axis2 versions used in WSO2 products are in WSO2 repository. For example, WSO2 Application Server 5.1.0 uses [axis2 1.6.1-wso2v9](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.1.0/dependencies/axis2/1.6.1-wso2v9/) according to [Carbon Release Matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/).

I hope this helps!